# Find the solution to $x^{(\log_5 x^2 + \log _5 x-12)}=\frac{1}{x^4}$

Tags: functions, logarithms

> Find the solution to $x^{(\log_5 x^2 + \log _5 x-12)}=\frac{1}{x^4}$

I equated their exponents,

That gave me $\log_5 x = \frac{8}{3}$

But the answer given in my book is $1$.

Obviously, 1 satisfies the equation. But my question, how can I get 1 as a solution by actually solving it.

When I tried to graph the function, the graphing calculator showed just 1 as a solution. Why doesn't it show the solution that I have got as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your calculator show if you plot the range $x=50..100?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $x>0$; instead of the logarithm in base $x$, consider the logarithm in base $5$ or any other base:
$$
(\log_5(x^2)+\log_5x-12)\log_5x=-4\log_5x
$$
that becomes, setting $y=\log_5x$,
$$
(3y-8)y=0
$$
so $y=0$ or $3y-8=0$. Thus the solutions are $x=1$ or $x=5^{8/3}$.

On the other hand, if the first term is $(\log_5x)^2$, rather than $\log_5(x^2)$, the equation would become
$$
(y^2+y-8)y=0
$$
with solutions
$$
y=0,\quad y=\frac{-1+\sqrt{33}}{2},\quad y=\frac{-1-\sqrt{33}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you were using 
$$x^{(\log_5 x^2 + \log _5 x-12)}=\frac{1}{x^4}\implies \log_5 x^2 + \log _5 x-12 =-4,$$
but it is only true when $x>0$ and $x\ne 1$.

Of course $x>0$ holds because it is the input of a logarithmic function. But you don't have $x\ne 1$. That's why you missed a solution.

Comment: But then why wasn't the other solution also given by the graphing calculator? When I plugged the equation in it, it just showed the graph of x=1.

Comment: I think $x=5^{8/3}$ is also a solution. I'm not sure why the calculator didn't give you that one.

Comment: Perhaps just because $x=5^{8/3}$ is too large.

Answer (score 1):

If the book claims, that $1$ is the only real solution, it is wrong. Your value
$$x = 5^{8/3} = e^{\frac{8}{3} \ln 5} \approx 73.1$$ is indeed a solution of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

What you did (probably) was the following:

$$x^{\log_5 x^2+\log_5 x-12} = \frac{1}{x^4} = x^{-4} \implies \log_5 x^2+\log_5 x-12 = -4$$

By doing so, you removed the possibility of $x = 1$.

As you know, $1$ raised to any power is simply one, so $x = 1$ is a trivial solution and doesn’t really require solving. Just note that $x$ is valid for the domain of $\log_5 x^2$ and $\log_5 x$.

---

Your other solution is valid. Let $x = 5^{\frac{8}{3}}$.

$$\log_5 \big(5^{\frac{8}{3}}\big)^2+\log_5 5^{\frac{8}{3}}-12 = \log_5 \big(5^{\frac{8}{3}}\big)^3-12 = \log_5 5^8-12 = 8-12 = -4$$

On both sides, you get

$$\big(5^{\frac{8}{3}}\big)^{-4}$$

Answer (score 1):

We need

$$\log_5 x^2 + \log _5 x-12=-4 \iff \log_5 (x^3)=8$$

that is

$$x=5^\frac83$$

the other solution $x=1$ is obtained by inspection from the original equation.

Comment: @KM101 Opssss...thanks I fix!

Comment: No problem! :-)